# What are the damage Sharpness modifiers in MH4U?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

[Wikia](http://monsterhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Weapon_Mechanics) claims the MH4U sharpness modifiers are as follows:

```
Red    0.50 physical, 0.2500 element
Orange 0.75 physical, 0.5000 element
Yellow 1.00 physical, 0.7500 element
Green  1.05 physical, 1.0000 element
Blue   1.20 physical, 1.0625 element
White  1.32 physical, 1.1250 element
Purple 1.45 physical, 1.2000 element
```

This is the same as what they report for MH4.

However, a [GameFaqs thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/762804-monster-hunter-4-ultimate/71224802) referencing [a Japanese source](http://www.dopr.net/formonsterhunter/%E3%80%90MH4%E3%80%91%E6%96%AC%E3%82%8C%E5%91%B3%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8B%E7%89%A9%E7%90%86%E3%83%BB%E5%B1%9E%E6%80%A7%E5%80%A4%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E8%A3%9C%E6%AD%A3) claims:

```
Red    0.500 physical, 0.2500 element
Orange 0.750 physical, 0.5000 element
Yellow 1.000 physical, 0.7500 element
Green  1.125 physical, 1.0000 element
Blue   1.250 physical, 1.0625 element
White  1.320 physical, 1.1250 element
Purple 1.440 physical, 1.2000 element
```

I am sceptical of the GameFaqs thread, because the OP claims purple was nerfed while green, blue, and white were buffed, which can't all be true unless I have the wrong numbers for other games and purple hasn't been 1.5 since MHFU and Tri, and because a comment on the source adds a correction for green (-> 1.05) and questions the value for blue (-> 1.20). Personally I would be quite surprised to see a return to the MHFU values for physical green and blue.

**Does anyone know what the sharpness modifiers really are?** If you can link to a reliable source (e.g. involving a dump) that would be great. I have a plugin for comparing weapon damage and it's useless if I don't have good data.

Comment: These are not very different, the decimal has only expanded, therefore the differences are slim.

Comment: @JDWhaler You are wrong, take a closer look at the physical multipliers. The biggest difference is green, at 1.05 in one list and 1.125 in the other. That's +5% of base and +12.5% of base, which is a pretty significant difference. Blue has +20% and +25%, also fairly significant. Purple also differs but not significantly (+44% and +45%).